# How to install uBlock Origin for Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

Is there any way to install [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/master/README.md) on Safari?

I'm currently using macOS 10.11.2 with Safari 9.0.2 on a 2012 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 15):

**2019 Update**: uBlock Origin is no longer available as of Safari 13.

More detail can be found in this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari/issues/158):

> uBO will no longer [work] with Safari, use Firefox or a new "content blocker" app.

---

**2018 Update**

[uBlock-Safari Installation](https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari#installation):

> The preferred method of installation is to install from the [extension
>   gallery](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.el1t.uBlock-3NU33NW2M3). This allows the extension to update automatically, and
>   the submissions are approved by Apple.

Comment: With Safari 13 it's not possible, unfortunately. Apple has removed it.

Comment: @RostyslavDruzhchenko - thanks for prompting an update! Updated.

Answer (score 7):

Now there is, thanks to a new fork of [uBlock Origin for Safari](https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari) by el1t. As of writing, as it's still in alpha, you will need to download the extension from GitHub and then install it by clicking on the downloaded file.

Comment: **This is no longer under development** since Apple has crippled uBlock Origin by changing and making Safari more "secure".

Answer (score 5):

It's past 2021, and uBlock Origin is crippled and no longer available for Safari. However, a new browser built on the same technologies as Safari (Webkit), called the **Orion browser**, is now under development for both macOS and ios. And it has built-in support for uBlock Origin (and many other popular extensions). A beta version of the browser is now available and can be downloaded from here - [Orion Browser](https://browser.kagi.com/). (It, unfortunately, is the only option currently for those who want all the features of Safari with uBlock Origin too).

Answer (score 3):

Nope, but you can install [uBlock](https://www.ublock.org). Unfortunately, it seems like its development has stalled recently, but it still works for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

As of Safari 12.0, with the switch from the Extension Gallery to the Safari Extensions, uBlock Origin is no longer officially supported. You can read a more detailed discussion of the situation here: [Safari 12 compatible versions of ad blockers fail to block many ads](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337094/safari-12-compatible-versions-of-ad-blockers-fail-to-block-many-ads/337097#337097)

There is, at least for now, an officially supported workaround on the [uBlock-Safari Github page](https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari#installation):

1. Clone [uBlock-Safari](https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari) and [uAssets](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets) into the same parent directory
2. Build by running `./tools/make-safari.sh` in uBlock-Safari's directory
   3.Install the unpacked extension through Safari's Extension Builder

   - Show the `Develop` menu in Safari by going to `Preferences > Advanced` and checking `Show Develop menu in menu bar`
   - In Safari, load the Extension Builder (Develop > Show Extension Builder)
   - Click the + button in the bottom left corner and "Add Extension"
   - Select dist/build/uBlock0.safariextension
   - Click install and enter your password

You will have to repeat step 3 each time you restart Safari, but your settings will be saved, so it's only a few extra clicks.

It's impossible to know how long Apple will allow this to work, but for for now it seems to be the least bad option (and much better than using uBlock which is  shady and unrelated to uBlock Origin)